# How to send compressed file with Amazon-SES to gmail?

Tags: bash, gmail, amazon-ses

I'm using a bash script to create a temp directory containing files

Then I zip the file & send it via Amazon-SES

I'm running into the problem where gmail doesn't display attachments.. it doesn't support the temp directory format within a zip folder...

How do I compress the folder & allow it to be visible in gmail?

[image]
The email should show the attached image with a document in a "tmp" folder... but the email attachment shows up blank[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ialkx.png)

Comment: Can you show us how it's currently displayed and how it's supposed to display in gmail?

Comment: @jellycsc Sure, I uploaded an image of what the contents of the folder should look like.

It shows up when I download the folder, but it doesn't show up when opening it on gmail